# How to explicitly kill the process with PID 1 from inside a container?

Tags: docker

For demonstration purposes, I would like to kill the process with PID 1 from inside a container. But apparently, `kill 1` doesn't work:

```
$ sudo docker run -it centos
[root@3752d3a44f10 /]# ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
   15 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
[root@3752d3a44f10 /]# kill 1
[root@3752d3a44f10 /]# kill -9 1
[root@3752d3a44f10 /]# kill -SEGV 1
[root@3752d3a44f10 /]# <-- shell is still running
```

Is there a way to explicitly kill the process with PID 1 from inside a container? How?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PID 1 is a special PID which will ignore certain signals unless handlers are explicitly created. Docker has some documentation on this:

> Note: A process running as PID 1 inside a container is treated specially by Linux: it ignores any signal with the default action. So, the process will not terminate on SIGINT or SIGTERM unless it is coded to do so.

From here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground

To kill PID 1 you will have to explicitly declare the handler for the SIGTERM signal or, in current versions of Docker, pass the `--init` flag in the `docker run` command to instrument [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini).

Comment: Thank you very much @edaemon, especially for having mentioned the `--init` flag I wasn't aware of!

Answer (score 2):

Also have this problem, solving by use follwing docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
trap "trap - SIGTERM && kill -- -$$" SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT SIGHUP

some_app &
wait
```

You can 'kill 1' somewhere to exit this whole container.

Comment: What does it help to run it the background and then `wait` on it?  Why not just run it?

Comment: amazing! this is the only solution that works